# A result and a counterexample on completeness of measure and measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can I prove that the following implications are valid if and only if the measure $\mu$ is complete?

$1.$ If $f$ is measurable and $f=g$ a.e. then $g$ is measurable.

$2.$ If $f_n$ is measurable for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_n \to f$ $\mu-a.e.$ then $f$ is measurable.

Why are $1.$ and $2.$ not valid if the measure is not complete?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mu$ is not complete, so that there exists a set $N$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and a subset $E\subset N$ which is not measurable. Then

1. Take $f=0$ and $g = \mathbb{1}_N+\mathbb{1}_E$.
2. Take $f_n = 0$ for all $n$ and $f = \mathbb{1}_N + \mathbb{1}_E$.